# How to have two networks together in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a network in TensorFlow which uses tf.nn.embedding_lookup because of that the input placeholder is self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="input_x"), I want to add an MLP network to this current network such that input of the MLP network is the input of the current network. For the MLP network, I need a float input type, but the type of current input placeholder is tf.int32. so when I run the code it shows the error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `with tf.variable_scope` and `with tf.name_scope` for both networks solved the problem.